# Optional spaces \s+? are not honoured in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am expecting the following regex to allow 0-n spaces between operators, but it is forcing at least one. Can someone please correct the error of my ways?

```
((\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+\s+?[\+\-\/\*]\s+?)+)(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)
```

Examples

```
24*3.2
24 * 3.2
```

Only the 2nd example is allowed through.

I understood `\s+?` should be an optional number of spaces?

[Playpen](https://regexr.com/55j19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+?` (or more generally `?` following *any* other quantifier) is a [non-greedy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). It does *not* mean “make the preceding match optional”.

Use `*` instead of `+?`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `\s*`, i.e., 0 or more white spaces. 
Your `\s+?` says 1 or more white spaces and non greedy match for spaces.
The ? modifier after * or + means non-greedy match.